# Cannot change border color in OutlinedButton

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to change the border of my `OutlinedButton` in my `main.dart` but it doesn't seem to be working. I've been looking around and it seems like I need to add `BorderSide`. This is what my `outlinedButtonTheme` looks like:

```dart
              outlinedButtonTheme: OutlinedButtonThemeData(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
                    (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                      if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed)) {
                        return AppColors.SecondaryButtonPressed;
                      }

                      return AppColors.SecondaryButton;
                    },
                  ),
                  minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all<Size>(Size(335, 60)),
                  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<OutlinedBorder>(
                      RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    side: BorderSide(
                        style: BorderStyle.solid,
                        color: AppColors.Primary,
                        width: 1), // <-- this doesn't work?
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                  )),
                  foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                      AppColors.SecondaryButtonText),
                  textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all<TextStyle>(TextStyle(
                    color: AppColors.SecondaryButtonText,
                    fontSize: 14 * FONT_SCALE_FACTOR,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  )),
                ),
              ),
```

Shown above where BorderSide is. It doesn't seem like this is working at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There were a few things I missed from looking at the docs within `ButtonStyle`.

I added

```dart
side: MaterialStateProperty.all<BorderSide>(
                      BorderSide(color: AppColors.Primary)),
```

in `ButtonStyle` and it worked rather than adding it inside

```dart
shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<OutlinedBorder>(
                      RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    side: BorderSide(
                        style: BorderStyle.solid,
                        color: AppColors.Primary,
                        width: 1), // <-- this doesn't work at all in shape.
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12)),
                  )),
```

Answer (score 9):

This works for me:

```
OutlinedButton(onPressed: () {},
    style: ButtonStyle(shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0))),
                  side: MaterialStateProperty.all(BorderSide(
                    color: AppColors.blue,
                  )),
                ),)
```

Answer (score 6):

I followed the guide at [new material buttons](http://flutter.dev/go/material-button-migration-guide) and solved it like this:

```
OutlinedButton.icon(
          style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
            shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5)),
            ),
          ).copyWith(
            side: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<BorderSide>(
              (Set<MaterialState> states) {
                if (states.contains(MaterialState.disabled)) return null;
                return BorderSide(
                  color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                  width: 3,
                );
                // Defer to the widget's default.
              },
            ),
          ),
     ...
```

I needed to specify a different color for a disabled vs active state because I wanted the border to have a color when its active and no color when its disabled (returning null because by default border has no color unlike the old button)

Comment: You're awesome, it's working fine with new **OutlinedButton**

Comment: how can we define it in main.dart under themedata? Thanks

Comment: You can use the `outlinedButtonTheme` of the `ThemeData` and provide `OutlinedButtonThemeData` with the same style value.  Check out page 7 of the link in this answer

Answer (score 5):

Use style property:

```
  OutlinedButton(
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Text('Button'),
  style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
    side: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.red),
  ),
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use **side** property of OutlinedButton. Don't use it inside the shape property of OutlinedButton.

```
                              OutlinedButton(
                                onPressed: () {},
                                style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
     // side: BorderSide(width:1.0, color: Colors.red), // DON'T USE HERE
                                  ),
                                  side: BorderSide(width:1.0, color: Colors.red),
                                  minimumSize: Size( width * 0.25, height * 0.04),
                                ),
                                child: Text('Decline', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),),
                              ),
```