# How to change border colour of OutlinedButton

Tags: flutter, button

I would like to change border color of OutlinedButton. Could you tell me how to do it?

```
OutlinedButton(
              onPressed: null,
              style: ButtonStyle(
                shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
                  RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              child: const Text("Kontynuuj jako gość",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Color(0xffffffff)),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center),
            ),
```

I tried [Cannot change border color in OutlinedButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66678974/cannot-change-border-color-in-outlinedbutton) but it does not work.

Comment: add a side: BordeSide(color: Colors.green), to your roundedrectangleborder.

Comment: @lrsvmb does not work. Still no colour apperad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify side parameter of a `ButtonStyle`

```dart
ButtonStyle(
  side: MaterialStateProperty.all(BorderSide(color: Colors.deepOrange)),
  shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(
    RoundedRectangleBorder(
      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.deepOrange),
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
    ),
  ),
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
 OutlinedButton(
     onPressed: null,
     style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 5),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25))),
     child: const Text("Kontynuuj jako gość",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Color(0xffffffff)),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center),
 ),
```